# How can output the pointer (line number) from running powershell script?

Tags: powershell, line-numbers

I am looking a way to get output the pointer (line number) from running powershell script and write into a selfmade Log-File.

```
function DebugMode {

param([int]$linenumber,[String]$message)
$Date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
$logfilepath ="$scriptpath\Debug_$Date.log"

$Date  + " - "+ $linenumber + " - " +$message |  Out-File -FilePath $logfilepath -Append}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack) cmdlet for this:

```
function Write-Log ($Message) {
    $linenumber = (Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptLineNumber
    $Date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
    $Date  + " - "+ $linenumber + " - " +$message
}

Write-Log 'test'
```

```
20230104 - 7 - test
```